# Execution failed for task mergedebugresources cordova

Tags: cordova, gradle

While running `cordova build android` it shows me error:

```
execution failed for task mergedebugresources
Multiple task action failures occured:
A failure occured while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
Android resources compilation failed
AAPT:C:\Windows\System32\PudziBreak\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug: error directory does not exist
```

...

Comment: Im dealing with issues since 2days. I have to manually update everything. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Try removing platform `cordova platform remove android` and then `cordova platform add android --verbose`. Check if there are any errors. And then build with --verbose flags. Also add as much info as you can, for example cordova version

Comment: @SidLeniwiec , I have the same problem, did you find solution for this?